# AWS SAM Local dotnetcore2.1 exception when running API Gateway

Tags: .net-core, aws-sam-cli

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- Docker for Windows v18.09.0
- AWS SAM CLI v0.10.0
- Python 3.7.0
- AWS CLI v1.16.67
- dotnet core sdk v2.1.403
- Powershell v5.1.17134.407

**Problem**

I'm following the [quickstart for AWS SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html) (as well as the readme generated once the init command is executed below), using the `dotnetcore2.1` runtime.

I've run the following command to initialise AWS SAM for use with `dotnetcore2.1`

```powershell
sam init --runtime dtonetcore2.1
```

Then I created the package by running

```powershell
build.ps1 --target=package
```

Finally I start the local API Gateway service by running

```powershell
sam local start-api
```

I then open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:3000/hello` where I'm presented with the following:

```powershell
PS C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Workspace\messaround\aws-sam\sam-app> sam local start-api
2019-01-04 10:39:15 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2019-01-04 10:39:15 Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
2019-01-04 10:39:15 You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2019-01-04 10:39:16  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-01-04 10:40:10 Invoking HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler (dotnetcore2.1)
2019-01-04 10:40:10 Decompressing C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Workspace\messaround\aws-sam\sam-app\artifacts\HelloWorld.zip

Fetching lambci/lambda:dotnetcore2.1 Docker container image......
2019-01-04 10:40:13 Mounting C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq0zka7a7 as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
2019-01-04 10:40:14 Exception on /hello [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 246, in _raise_for_status
response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.35/containers/102dda11417068e01873242be2383c78c7ad4e2739fd4f8b42c1e0ea494d2bbb/start

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\apigw\local_apigw_service.py", line 153, in _request_handler
self.lambda_runner.invoke(route.function_name, event, stdout=stdout_stream_writer, stderr=self.stderr)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\lib\local_lambda.py", line 85, in invoke
self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\lambdafn\runtime.py", line 86, in invoke
self._container_manager.run(container)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\manager.py", line 98, in run
container.start(input_data=input_data)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\container.py", line 187, in start
real_container.start()
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 390, in start
return self.client.api.start(self.id, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 1075, in start
self._raise_for_status(res)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 248, in _raise_for_status
raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq0zka7a7': mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/user_name/AppData: permission denied")
2019-01-04 10:40:14 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2019 10:40:14] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 -
2019-01-04 10:40:14 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2019 10:40:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

**What I've tried**

*Resetting the shared drive credentials*
Initially I though this was a permissioning error between my Windows drive and the VM running docker... After searching the docker forums I found [this article](http://peterjohnlightfoot.com/docker-for-windows-on-hyper-v-fix-the-host-volume-sharing-issue/) which I've followed.  However this doesn't seem to have changed the error message

Any suggestions would be greatly received. Thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue here right now.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I fixed my problem:

When SAM CLI sees a zip, it unzip into a temp directory (looks to be C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq0zka7a7 in your case).

Docker must have access to that folder.

In my case, I've created a local user to give Docker access to shared drives and that local user didn't have access to C:/Users/user_name.

I gave it access and got my problem sorted. Maybe you can fix it the same way.

Try to run the following:

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users/user_name:/data alpine ls /data
```

It should list c:/Users/user_name content if all is fine.

Good luck!